# ConstraintLayout automatically add layout_width/layout_height to views without it

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I define layout_width and layout_height in style, so it actually set, but IDE dont see my styles and autocomplete my code with
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"

code example:
when i make build or switch between design/text IDE add to TextView
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_contact_phone"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_contact_phone"
    style="@style/FormValue"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_contact_phone"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

forgot to mention:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
Androd Studio 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug -- could you please file it on code.google.com? thanks!

Comment: hope i did it right 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225562&thanks=225562&ts=1476866784

Answer (score 0):

I Found the same issue,I found android:layout_height="0dp" was added because visible="gone" was added for this view,in my case,to remove it and set Visible programmatically works,hope it works for you!